Is the framed cracked?
I have noticed this scratch/crack on my canyon exceed cf6 frame. Can I get someone else’s opinion on what they think about it?
I have never overtightened the seatpost bolt to more than specified and inside the seatpost it looks quite nice. I haven’t seen anything unusual there.

Where on the bike is this?

the very top part of the seatpost

@samokosik is this a frame with an integrated seatpost ?   Or is this at the bottom of the seatpost where it enters the frame?

This question is similar to: What do I do when I am unsure if damaged carbon fiber is safe to use or needs replacing or repairing?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

An universal method in similar cases is to apply some mild (non-destructive) mechanical tension over the detail in few different directions and see if the suspected crack changes in appearance.
Even if you don't see the crack widening, a change in color or length will reveal microscopic movements.
A magnifying tool is an option as well.

Can you describe what that might look like here, e.g. squeeze the tube lightly, lever the seatpost lightly?

It could be just a crack in the paint or lacquer surface.
It could be a crack in the carbon that has cracked the paint surface.
It could even be a deep scratch.
But from a photograph, we'll never know.
Go to a carbon repair expert. In person.
Photo shows nothing.

I will probably check it. Just to be sure. However, I talked to several people and it seems to be just in paint. Mainly because inside the seat-tube (where there is no paint), carbon does not seem damaged in any way. If it was damaged, how much can I expect to pay for repair. I don’t think getting a new frame would be necessary.

Carbon repair can be very cost effective, much cheaper than repairing a metal frame. But paint repair can be costly. If repair is necssessary (it may not be), you can paint the repaired area matt black to protect from UV. It's cheap but not so pretty, if you don't mind to have the frame no longer appear as it left the factory. Whatever happens, it is good you are cautious but the material is generally very robust when used as intended, so do not lose sleep. @samokosik

Sometimes we can't tell what the problem is until it is allowed to get a little worse.
